# 0-tensor field is the real value function

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I was reading Lee's smooth manifold,in page 317.

there is a relation about the **tensor bundle** that is:

$$T^{(0,0)}TM = M \times \mathbb{R}   \tag{1}$$

then the book says:**0-tensor field** is the same as a continuous real value function.

> The question are two :
>
> - why (1) holds
> - how to see the 0-tensor field on the tangent bundle as a real value function.

for the second question :By definition tensor field is section $A:M \to T^{(0,0)}TM$

But if (1) holds $A:M \to M\times \mathbb{R}$ is not a real value function as $M\to \mathbb{R}$?

(where bundle of mix tensor is defined as $T^{(k, l)} T M=\coprod_{p \in M} T^{(k, l)}\left(T_{p} M\right)$)

I don't know how to make this two question very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first point holds because
$$T^{(0,0)}TM=\coprod_{p\in M}T^{(0,0)}(T_pM)=\coprod_{p\in M}\mathbb{R}=M\times\mathbb{R},$$

where the second equality is a convention ($T^{(0,0)}(T_pM)$ is $0$ copies of $T_pM$ and $0$ copies of $(T_pM)^*$, as usual you chose "$0$ copies" to mean the identity element for the operation you are dealing with - there it is $\mathbb{R}$ since the operation is the tensor product over $\mathbb{R}$).

The second point is that the map $A:M\to M\times\mathbb{R}$ has to check $\pi\circ A=\mathrm{id}_M$, where $\pi:M\times \mathbb{R}\to M$ is the first projection, since by definition a tensor field is a section of your bundle. So a $0$-tensor field is written $A(x)=(x,f(x))$, and so they are the same as real-valued functions if you use the identification

$$\varphi:\Gamma(T^{(0,0)}(TM))\to C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R}),\varphi(A)=\mathrm{pr}_2\circ A,$$

where $\Gamma(T^{(0,0)}(TM))$ is the set of $0$-tensors (i.e. the set of all sections of the bundle $T^{(0,0)}(TM)$) and where $\mathrm{pr}_2:M\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is the second projection.

Comment: thank you the identification $\varphi$ is the standard identification between graph of a function and function itself, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly that.